# before calling connect(), can I know which port number I'll use?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a client/server application using socking programing APIs.

On the client side, before calling connect(), can I know which port number I'll use?
What I have now is the socket file descriptor from calling socket(). I tried to use getsockname, but I only got 0 for port number.

Comment: Do you mean which socket you are connecting to, or which socket you'll be writing out on?

Answer (score 2):

There is no address/port assigned until you call `bind(2)` (with port=0 and/or addr=0). After bind, you can use getsockname.

Comment: And, of course, `connect` implies `bind` if it has not been explicitly called before.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend reading [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) if you're completely new to socket programming.

But to answer your question (I think) with a TCP socket, you need to know what remote port you are connecting to (i.e. that the server does the `bind()` too).  However, you typically (the client application programmer) don't specify the port the server uses to talk back.  It is chosen randomly by the TCP stack based on port numbers the client has available.

Comment: Those randomly chosen ports on the client side are typically known as 'Ephemeral ports'.

Comment: @VictorT.  Would you say this more is accurate now?

Comment: There's a problem. When I use bind(), I can get the port number correctly then. However, I am not able to get the correct ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call `bind()`, even with port number `0`. After that, `getsockname()` should give you the port.